# Unpacking a List of Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I'm trying to open up a pickle file of a large data set, but am running into an issue with the resultant data type. The result gives a list with an array inside, I need to unpack the list to get the array inside. I think it can be boiled down to the following example. Say I have

```
x = [array([1,1,1], [1,1,1])]
```

(type(x) = list)

I want to unpack this list so that it's just the array inside. I.e., I want

```
y = array([1,1,1], [1,1,1])
```

(type(y) = numpy.ndarray)

I'm relatively new to Python programming and could use a hand on how to do this easily. Please let me know if I need to clarify my question.

I'm not sure if it matters here, but I'm using Python 3.7.6.

---

EDIT

Looks like I made a mistake when putting in the array for x. To clarify, this is what I'm getting when I unpack the pickle file.

```
x = pandas.read_pickle(data_source)
print(x)
> [array([1,1,1],[1,1,1])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With array, I presume you are having a numpy array and you can't have something like:

```
np.array([1,1,1], [1,1,1])
```

which throws a `TypeError: data type not understood`.

You have to wrap a square bracket from outside like so:

```
np.array([[1,1,1], [1,1,1]])
```

---

To answer your question, you can do:

```
y = x[0]
```

which makes `y` a `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`.

Comment: Whoops, I knew that about the brackets. It was an oversight, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

so for this case of :

```
x = [array([1,1,1], [1,1,1])]
np.concatenate(x).ravel()
```

this should give you this:

> ```
> array([1,1,1], [1,1,1])
> ```